# GWT incubator table data ordering issue

Tags: gwt

I have implemented a gwt incubator table following the example at http://zenoconsulting.wikidot.com/blog:17

this works great however, the order of rows is not same as it is passed using the list object. 
the data in this example is set in the following part of the code:

```
public long showMessages(ArrayList<Message> list) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // update the count
        countLabel.setText("There are "+ list.size() + " messages.");
        // reset the table model data
        tableModel.setData(list);
        // reset the table model row count
        tableModel.setRowCount(list.size());
        // clear the cache
        cachedTableModel.clearCache();
        // reset the cached model row count
        cachedTableModel.setRowCount(list.size());
        // force to page zero with a reload
        pagingScrollTable.gotoPage(0, true);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return end - start;
    }
```

Please provide some solution to fix this issue.

Comment: See choosing the right collection http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65

Comment: awesome! thank you! somehow i ignored this part and internally down the line code was using a hashMap to manage table data which obviously does not retain the sort order. i changed it to linkedHashMap and it worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

awesome! thank you! somehow i ignored this part and internally down the line code was using a hashMap to manage table data which obviously does not retain the sort order. i changed it to linkedHashMap and it worked